# computing weighted average over numpy.ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

There two numpy.ndarray `A` and `B`; and both of which have shapes `(3,20,5)`. `C` is a `pandas.core.series.Series` with length `20`
I would like to compute a weighted average array `D` based on `A, B` and `C`, based on the formula

```
D[:,x,:] = A[:,x,:]*C[x]+B[:,x,:]*(1-C[x])
```

What’s the right way to implement this based on the best practice in Numpy, without iterating over the related `3-dimension array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
c = C.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
D = A*c + B*(1-c)
```

Comment: thanks, I have a question regarding the answer, so the c will be automatically broadcasted into the second dimension of both A and B. if A and B have shapes (3,20,20), how should we solve this?

Comment: If you still want to broadcast `c` over the second dimension then the same code will work (the last dimension of `c` is 1, so it will be broadcast over the last dimension of `A` and `B`). [Here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.05-computation-on-arrays-broadcasting.html#Rules-of-Broadcasting) is a nice summary of numpy broadcasting rules.